# How to reduce runtime of Julia code to find roots using "IntervalRootFinding.jl" package?

Tags: julia, interval-arithmetic

I am trying to find roots using the "IntervalArithmetic.jl", and "IntervalRootFinding.jl" package in Julia. It seems that the code is running for an infinite time, as it neither gives roots nor terminates at some point. The code is shown below-

```
using IntervalArithmetic, Plots, StaticArrays, IntervalRootFinding
α_x = α_y = 100 * (2..3)
γ_x = γ_y = (2..3)
K_y = 10 * (2/3..3/2)
u = 1

g( (x, y) ) = SVector(α_x * u - γ_x * x, α_y * u / ( 1 + x / K_y ) - γ_y * y)
X = IntervalBox(80..120, 5..20)
rts = roots(g, X)
@show rts
```

Could you please help me to solve the issue?
Thank you

Comment: You want the root of a vector values function? What would that even mean.

Comment: @MikaelÖhman I am taking help from the https://juliaintervals.github.io/IntervalRootFinding.jl/latest/. From my understanding it should provide an interval box containing 2 intervals corresponding to x and y. But the code is running continuously, neither giving any error nor result.

Comment: @MikaelÖhman Actually, the resultant column vector will contain two intervals corresponding to the roots of x and y.